# How to pass requestparam to another method in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm trying to pass my parameters to another method and save it to my respective repositories. I want to pass my parameters in `checkoutView` to `doOrder`. How do I do that?

Here's my Controller code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkout")
public class CheckoutController {


@Autowired
ProductRepository pRepo;

@Autowired
CustomerRepository cRepo;

@Autowired
InventoryRepository iRepo;

@RequestMapping(value = "", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView checkoutView(@RequestParam(value="val-name") String prodname, @RequestParam(value="val-qty") int qty, @RequestParam(value="val-price") double price, @RequestParam(value="amount") String amount) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("customerEntity", new CustomerEntity());
    mav.setViewName("/checkout");
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/new",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doOrder(@ModelAttribute CustomerEntity customerEntity, @ModelAttribute ProductEntity productEntity) {
//perform a save to their repositories
    return "redirect:/product-list";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `RedirectAttributes` of spring. it is a sub-interface of Model.

It is a preferred way to pass attributes to redirect target.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so dumb. I just have to transfer it to the method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView checkoutView() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("customerEntity", new CustomerEntity());
    mav.setViewName("/checkout");
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/new",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doOrder(@ModelAttribute CustomerEntity customerEntity, @ModelAttribute ProductEntity productEntity, @RequestParam(value="val-name") int prodname, @RequestParam(value="val-qty") int qty, @RequestParam(value="amount") double amount) {

    //perform a save to their repositories
    return "redirect:/product-list";
}
```